# How do I intersect DEM and a polyline?

Tags: qgis, dem, intersection

I'm working on QGIS, How do I intersect a DEM and a polyline to get the longitudinal section of a river?

Answer (score 3):

This is what the 'profile from line' plug-in is for :)

N.

Comment: There is also the `Profile` plugin which I find more useful.

Comment: Did you mean "Profile Tool" plugin? There is also a "Profile export" plugin in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Try the **Profile from Line** plugin. Make a line shapefile of the "longitudinal section" then run the plugin with your DEM and the line shape loaded. (Be sure to select the DEM raster in the plugin window). It creates a point layer with the DEM value as an attribute column.

Comment: It's creating a layer with only 2 points (at the ends of the line), I cannot understand why....

Comment: Most probably you have WGS84 4326 and the interval set to 4, which means 4 degrees of lat/lon. Try with an interval of 0.01, or a projected CRS with metres as units.

Comment: @Micha: Do you refer to the "Profile from line" plugin?

Comment: @Andre: Yes, I got the name wrong. Thanks for the correction.